# Java mysql like command

Tags: java, mysql, sql-like

I want to ask for help my code that will find relevant name from database according to id number.

My code find the name that i try to find.

BUT i want to send an error message when the program can not find ID number.

I tried many ways but always when it couldnt find ID number, it said build succesfull and show no error just quitted the program.

Thanks for your help.

```
public void search(String ID) throws SQLException {

    Statement mystate = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT*FROM users" +
        " WHERE id LIKE " + ID;

    ResultSet rs = mystate.executeQuery(sql);    

    while (rs.next()) {

        System.out.println("Your Name is " + rs.getString("name"));   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two big issues with your code:

1. You don't put SQL quotes around `ID`, so it looks like a keyword or identifer to the SQL parser
2. It's **wide open** to SQL-injection attacks (see below)

You want to use a `PreparedStatement`, which deals with both of those for you. Then just use a flag for whether you saw anything:

```
public void search(String ID) throws SQLException {
    boolean sawOne = false;

    PreparedStatement mystate = con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id LIKE ?"
    );
    mystate.setString(1, ID);
    ResultSet rs = mystate.executeQuery(mystate);    

    while (rs.next()) {
        sawOne = true;
        System.out.println("Your Name is " + rs.getString("name"));   
    }
    if (!sawOne) {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
}
```

I'm assuming `ID` already has a wildcard on it (or that you really don't want one).

Or if you know there will be only one match, or you only want one match even if there's more than one, you can add a

```
mystate.setMaxRows(1);
```

...before `executeQuery()`, and then just use `if/else`, no need for the flag:

```
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Your Name is " + rs.getString("name"));   
} else {
    System.out.println("...");
}
```

Obligatory SQL-injection link: http://bobby-tables.com/

And cartoon:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public void search(String ID) throws SQLException {

    Statement mystate = con.createStatement();

    String sql = "SELECT*FROM users" +
            " WHERE id LIKE " + ID;

    ResultSet rs = mystate.executeQuery(sql);    

    if(rs.next()) {

        System.out.println("Your Name is " + rs.getString("name"));   
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Id not found");   
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice SQL injection vulnerability there.

Comment: Which the OP was asking for our help with.

Comment: " when it couldnt find ID number, it said build succesfull and show no error just quitted the program." that is what OP asked for, he didnt ask to sanitize his database nor make it hack proof

Comment: Anyway thanks for pointing it out @T.J.Crowder it would be good for the future readers aswell

Comment: thank u for your helps. im newbie. i just finished basics of java and im trying to make a little project to improve myself. i will care ur warnings. ty so much